# Best way to migrate IIS6 from one server to another

Tags: iis, migration

I need to move all my sites on a server with IIS 6 to another one, that has same OS (Windows Server 20003) and same IIS version. I'm trying to understand which is the best way to do it. Searching on Google I've found that there are at least 2 methods, one uses IIS Migration Tool, and another Web Deployment Tool.

I don't know which method is best, it also seems that both methods can export one site at once, and I have about 100 sites hosted.

What would you do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IIS 6.0, it is possible to create portable backup of your existing Metabase. You will need to select "Encrypt backup using password" option for the same. This will create a backup omitting AdminACL's of that machine. This backup file is located in C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\Metaback folder. You will need the copy the .MD0 and .SD0 file and put it in the same folder location on another IIS Server. Now, restore the backup.

check this out [Backing Up and Restoring the Metabase in IIS 6.0](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/d40b56ee-90d4-45e1-9b82-4aaea90eb02e.mspx?mfr=true)